# I have a row with 6 col-xs-12 divs and I want to only display 2 in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am wondering if there is a default bootstrap way to handle this or it should be done through jquery. the row is to long in mobile and I want to only have two of the block to show in mobile with a button that would work like a accordion and display the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make them col-xs-6 and you should end up with 3 "rows" of 2-column divs, not?

Edit: nevermind, now I got it. You could add a CSS class to those divs and just hide them on narrow viewports, use [Bootstrap's collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) feature in some way, or jQuery.